# Angular Js Factory

Tags: angularjs, factory, angularjs-factory

I have a working version of the factory

```
function queryStaticDatabase (filterCondition, url, callback)
{ // should make server REST call in real scenario
    console.log(filterCondition);
    var recordsPerPage = filterCondition.recordsPerPage;
    var pageNumber = filterCondition.pageNumber;

    $http.get(url).success(function (data) {

                 console.log(data);
        callback({ // ajax callback in real scenario
            totalRecordsCount: totalRecordsCount,
            records: filteredData
        });

    });
}

return {
    query: queryStaticDatabase
}
```

I tried to change the code in the following way

```
    var query =
       function (filterCondition, url, callback) { // should make server REST call in real scenario
           console.log(filterCondition);
           var recordsPerPage = filterCondition.recordsPerPage;
           var pageNumber = filterCondition.pageNumber;
           $http.get(url).success(function (data) {



               callback({ // ajax callback in real scenario
                   totalRecordsCount: totalRecordsCount,
                   records: filteredData
               });
           });

       };
    return (query);
});
```

Though it looks syntactically correct. the modified factory is not working. I m new to AngularJs and please help me with this

Answer (score 2):

If you haven't changed how you are using the factory in controller then the return object structure is different.

In the first version you return an object that has property `query` so you can use `myFactory.query()`

In the second you only return the function so it would be `myFactory()` in controller

if you want things the same in controller  you would need to change

```
return (query);
```

to

```
return{
   query : query
}
```

returning the object with properties allows you to add properties to factory later without changing anything in controllers whereas changing the controllers now to only see the function would not make this easily extendable in the future

Comment: +1. Thanks It worked. Its more on the understanding part. I have one more query.
As you have explained, in the second version, I m returning the function. And as per definition of factory, its sounds perfect.
But to your first point,  you mentioned, I m returning an object that has the property query.. Can you please explain it. I m new to this and would like to understand it better

Comment: object literal ==>`{propertyName: value}`  . The reson this is betetr is can add aproperty without impacting code elesewhere

Comment: Thanks. still one thing which I m not able to clearly understand is, from c# perspective , instead of directly calling queryStaticDatabase , why we need to go by this method of calling by property. Is there a good article where I can read about this and understand it?

Comment: because of inheritance

Comment: Sorry Charli. didn't get you:(

Comment: if you are using angular you really need to understand what prototypical inheritance is...and how it works. it is the foundation of angular scopes. Read up on angular scopes and inheritance. If you don't understand the basics of that concept will have a very difficult time working with angular